# Passing data between webpages

Tags: php, javascript

I have a webpage with a form on it. The heading of the form is this:

```
           <form name="sw" METHOD ="POST" ACTION="logger1.php">
```

After some event has happened, a javascript function submits the form like this:

```
           document.forms["sw"].submit();
```

The php file logs the data from the form in a text file on the server, and then redirects the browser to another page. My issue is that I want to examine one of the values in the form from the previous page on the page that the browser is redirected to. I am completely lost. help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append `?info=hello` to the end of the URL it redirects to, then retrieve it in PHP with `$_GET['info']`

Comment: This is the command in the PHP file I use for redirection: header("Location: http://www.URL.co.uk/page1.htm"); I could add it on the end. Would that be header("Location: http://www.URL.co.uk/page1.htm" + ?formVariable);

Comment: Close. It would be `header("Location: URL.co.uk/page1.htm?formVar=$formVariable");` Then, on page1.htm, you can retrieve $formVariable by accessing `$_GET['formVar'];`

Comment: Okay so it worked with ."?".$_POST['_varName']);, so the variable is passed in the URL.  How could I retrieve that using a javascript command? $GET('_varName')?

Comment: You can get it in javascript [if you want](http://failchad.blogspot.com/2009/01/accessing-get-variables-in-javascript.html), but you're better off just putting a snippet of PHP in there. Something like `javaVar = <?=$_GET['formVar']?>;`

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using sessions? The `$_SESSION[]` array might keep your previously posted variable between pages.

Answer (score 2):

Basically all the form information is being passed to the "logger1.php" file in the POST method.
So you need to see what the code in the "logger1.php" file is and see exactly how the file is redirecting once it's done doing what it does.
Then you can possibly append the variable you want passed on to the redirect method in the GET method.

Lets say the variable you want to pass on is:

```
$_POST['Some_variable']
```

and the redirect method is something like:

```
header('Location: some_file.php');
```

then you can append it this way:

```
header('Location: some_file.php?variable_name='.$_POST['Some_variable']);
```

Comment: In my opinion session should be preferred to GET requests for security reasons. GET requests can be seen easily by the end user at it appears in his URL, while $_SESSION is at least hidden in his cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The information is not passed when the browser is redirected so there is no way to access it.

Comment: Unless you add it to $_SESSION, in that case your variable will live on :D

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this would be to store the value in a database.  If you are using ASP.NET the easiest way to do this would be to set up a SQL Server Express database.  They are free until you go over 10GB.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you put the variable that you want to look at as a get variable added to the url of the redirected page like so `http://yourdomain/thepage.php?var=variable`